# ListView - Why can't I see any selected items?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I try to do somthing when the user select item in the ListView.
I have tried this code:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            q = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index;
        }
```

but it doesn't work and throws an exception that says that the count of 'listView1.SelectedItems' is 0.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: It is because the event is also called when __nothing__ is selected (anymore). So you __always__ need to check for `SelectedItems.Count>0`

Comment: @TaW thank's. it works. write it as an answer if you want I'll accept it.

Comment: No, sorry but this is too small a problem to create an answer and let it go into the eternal SO archives.

Comment: @TaW you should always use `SelectedItems.Any();`

Comment: They are not really different, esp, since the event is most likely caused by a (slow) user action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check for the listview items count.
If items are empty then there will be an exception.

Comment: Please add an example, and use `SelectedItems.Any();` instead of count since it is the best practice